# Error on hangman game trying to replace underscore for letter

Tags: python

This is the error I am getting. I am still developing it, I just have hit a blocking point have tried looking farther into it on stackoverflow, while also trying to slice it. I am not understanding why its an item assignment other then that I am looping position which is a list. So maybe that is causing that part but I need to loop through that to get what letter position was correct to change the string. I have been stuck for about 2 hours. Thanks.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HangMan.py", line 66, in <module>
    checkchoice(guessletter(),word)
  File "HangMan.py", line 59, in checkchoice
    board[x] = choice
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

˚

```
#HANGMAN GAME
import random

wordlist = ["apple", "banana", "game", "windows", "baseball"]
special_characters = "!@#$%^&*()-+?_=,<>/\"\':"
choice = ""
word = ""
hangman = ["H", "A", "N", "G", "M", "A", "N"]
wrong = 0

def randomword():
    word = random.choice(wordlist)
    return word

def createboard(word):
    letters = 0
    for x in word:
        letters += 1
    return "_" * letters

def guessletter():
    while True:
        try:
            choice = input("Choose a letter: ")
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry that was not a valid choice.")
            continue
        if choice.isdigit():
            print("Sorry no digits allowed.")
            continue
        elif any(c in special_characters for c in choice):
            print("Sorry no special characters allowed.")
            continue
        else:
            return choice

def checkchoice(choice, word):
    count = 0
    position = []
    global wrong
    global board
    correct = False
    for x in word:
        if choice == x:
            correct = True
            position.append(count)
            pass
        else:
            pass
        count +=1
    if correct == False:
        wrong += 1
        print("Oof looks like you missed.")
        print(hangman[0:wrong])
    else:
        #ERROR HERE
        for x in position:
            board[x] = choice
        
word = randomword()
board = createboard(word)
print(board)
print(word)
while True:
    checkchoice(guessletter(),word)
    print(board)
    print(wrong)
```

Comment: I've removed the [tag:pygame] tag. The [tag:pygame] tag addresses the [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) library, but is not intended for a game written in Python.

Answer (score 3):

This expression:

```
'_' * 8
```

evaluates to an 8-character string.

This expression:

```
['_'] * 8
```

evaluates to an 8-element list, each element being a string of length 1.

Strings are immutable; you can't replace one character.  Lists are mutable; you can replace one element.

So when you create the board, you need this:

```
def createboard(word):
    letters = 0
    for x in word:
        letters += 1
    return ["_"] * letters
```

Or more succinctly:

```
def createboard(word):
    return ["_"] * len(word)
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes total sense. That makes sense for one of the errors I was getting earlier. Appreciate the fast help!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: replace it with board = board[0:x] + choice + board[x+1:]

long answer: let me explain

A string is non-mutable unlike lists, Therefore you cannot assign something to a string

What i am doing her is saying

board[0:x] get the first char to the x'th char

add choice to the string

board[x+1:] get the x + 1 to the end char

example:

board is set to a value of `"hell_ ____"`

and x is 4
then board[0:x] is `"hell"`
choice is choice
and board[x+1:] is " _____"